# Where do we create Bundle for Workflow triggering at content level or site level

Tags: 2013, workflow

I am using Tridion 2013 SP1.I am bit confused about where do we create Bundle for triggering workflow.
Currently i create Bundle at site publication level and add items into it at same level.
From this i am able to trigger workflow also.

Can we create bundle at content level ? if i do so i cannot add item to it at site level?
If i localize it at site level after that also i cannot add items to it.

What is the best practice for creating bundle.

Answer (score 2):

If you localise a Bundle, then you can only change its Metadata and Title - You cannot add any items to the localised Bundle.

As you are seeing, you can add items from a parent Publication (i.e. your Content Publication) in to a Bundle.

From the scenario that you describe, I would suggest that you **create a Bundle within the Content Publication, and then add this in to another Bundle within your Website Publication**. You can then send the second Bundle (the one created at the Website level) containing any additional items (e.g. Pages) through Workflow.

The Bundle functionality (and especially how Bundles behave through Workflow) is described really well in the [About Bundles](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-30EB308F-8571-41B3-9EA5-26970DD975FA) section of the online documentation (login required).